# get list from xml using linq based on true if there is no true then select false condition tag element in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

here i am trying to get custName name if pirmaryCustCheck is true if not then i have to select false tag element , how can i achieve this 
xml :

```
<Root>
  <data>
    <office>Mumba</office>
    <officeId>1JC9FJBM</officeId>
    <customer>
        <custName>Yash</custName>
        <pirmaryCustCheck>true</pirmaryCustCheck>
        <id>8</id>
      </customer>
    <customer>
      <custName> Rahul</custName>
        <pirmaryCustCheck>false</pirmaryCustCheck>
        <id>9</id>
      </customer>
  </data>
</Root>
```

code :

```
   string pathd = @"C:\Users\admin\documents\newCust.xml";

            XDocument docss = XDocument.Load(pathd);


            var records = docss.Descendants("data").Select(x => new
            {

                office = (string)x.Element("office"),
                officeId = (string)x.Element("officeId"),
                customer = x.Elements("customer").Select(y => new
                {
                    custName = (string)y.Element("custName"),
                    pirmaryCustCheck = (bool)y.Element("pirmaryCustCheck"),
                    id = (string)y.Element("id")
                }).Where(y => y.pirmaryCustCheck == true).Select(c => new
                {
                    custName = c.custName,
                    Id = c.id
                })
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like below.

Data Set

```
<Root>
<data>
<office>Mumba</office>
<officeId>1JC9FJBM</officeId>
<customer>
    <custName>Yash</custName>
    <pirmaryCustCheck>true</pirmaryCustCheck>
    <id>8</id>
  </customer>
<customer>
  <custName> Rahul</custName>
    <pirmaryCustCheck>false</pirmaryCustCheck>
    <id>9</id>
  </customer>
 </data>
 <data>
<office>Mumba</office>
<officeId>1JC9FJBM</officeId>
<customer>
    <custName>Yash</custName>
    <pirmaryCustCheck>false</pirmaryCustCheck>
    <id>11</id>
  </customer>
<customer>
  <custName> Rahul Jain</custName>
    <pirmaryCustCheck>false</pirmaryCustCheck>
    <id>10</id>
  </customer>
</data>
```

Code -

```
string pathd = @"C:\Users\admin\documents\newCust.xml";

        XDocument docss = XDocument.Load(pathd);

        var customerTrue = docss.Descendants("data").Elements("customer").Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
        var customerFalse = docss.Descendants("data").Elements("customer").Select(x => x).LastOrDefault();

        var records = docss.Descendants("data").Select(x => new
        {

            office = (string)x.Element("office"),
            officeId = (string)x.Element("officeId"),
            customer = new
            {
                custName = (bool)x.Elements("customer").First().Element("pirmaryCustCheck") ? (string)x.Elements("customer").First().Element("custName") : (string)x.Elements("customer").Last().Element("custName"),
                pirmaryCustCheck = (bool)x.Elements("customer").First().Element("pirmaryCustCheck"),
                id = (bool)x.Elements("customer").First().Element("pirmaryCustCheck") ? (string)x.Elements("customer").First().Element("id") : (string)x.Elements("customer").Last().Element("id")
            }
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: getting error ,how is it going to be work? , can you explain me ,  i have to select values custName ,id  if there is pirmaryCustCheck = true ,(case when <customer> with true is missing ), if there is only false pirmaryCustCheck  in <customer> then false part element are going to be selected

Comment: Could you please post a sample data set you are looking as output?

Comment: if pirmaryCustCheck = true 
Output: Mumba,1JC9FJBM,Yash,8
if pirmaryCustCheck = true is missing and xml only have pirmaryCustCheck = false then 
output: Output: Mumba,1JC9FJBM,Rahul,9

Comment: So assuming there will only be 2 customer elements under each data element, you only want to verify the first customer element for true condition and in case for first element  - pirmaryCustCheck=false, we display data from 2nd element. Is that correct?

Comment: yes , if true then true condition else then it will fetch the false condition

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, its tested.

```
var customers = (from e in docss.Descendants("data").Elements("customer")
                         where (bool)e.Element("pirmaryCustCheck") == true
                         select new 
                         {
                             Name = (string)e.Element("custName"),
                             Id = (string)e.Element("id"),
                         }).ToList();
```